# Converter ImageIcon para Image ou ImageIcon para BufferedImage

Tags: java, imagem, conversão-de-tipo

Estou com problemas para encontrar formas de converter `ImageIcon` para `Image` ou se possível `ImageIcon` para `BufferedImage` para poder salvar a mesma no banco de dados. Dei umas pesquisadas na internet mas as informações encontradas estão meio confusas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obter uma instância de `Image` de um tipo `Imageicon` basta utilizar o método [`getImage()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#getImage--):

```
Image img = seuIcon.getImage();
```

simples assim ;).

E para converter para `BufferedImage`, tente conforme sugerido nesta [resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15053229/5524514):

```
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics g = bi.createGraphics();
// paint the Icon to the BufferedImage.
icon.paintIcon(null, g, 0,0);
g.dispose();
```

O ideal seria salvar apenas o caminho da imagem e ela em si em algum diretório do servidor, mas se quiser continuar e salvar no banco, geralmente o formato é blob, mas não precisa converter pra bufferedimage ou image.

Comment: Obrigado! Talvez possa usar seu exemplo para outras aplicações!

Comment: Fiz um File capiturando o BufferedImage diretamente dentro do Objeto e depois salvei com a qualidade máxima dentro do banco de dados! Obrigado mesmo assim Articuno.. bom sou novo aqui, como posso pontua-lo e fechar o tópico?

Comment: @Falco404 bom, "encerrar" não tem tem, mas quando a resposta é útil para quem pergunta, o autor pode aceitá-la, clicando no `v` ao lado, isso é a unica forma de demonstrar que a solução foi encontrada. Ou o proprio autor postando, se a solução dele for bem diferente da que alguem respondeu.

Comment: Obrigado! Acho que entendi!